# Using jQuery Quicksand plugin, need to link DIRECTLY to a filter

Tags: php, jquery, filter, quicksand

I have 2 pages. A home page and a videos page. The videos page has a selection of videos with the plugin enabled so you can view only Corporate Videos, or only Club Videos, etc...

On my home page, I need to have  special link, that will link to the videos page, and then have the plugin filter itself to Club Videos, for example.

Simply put, I want to have multiple links, linking directly to the right page with the right filter.

I do have a basic and adaptive knowledge so please advise, and I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Did I get this right: You basically need to be able to "pre–filter" using the Quicksand plugin based on a URL parameter (probably a hash)?